# PHP/MySQL SELECT LIMITER issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, limit

I posted this question before but I did not know the cause but now I do. The other question is way out of hand.

I am making a page function (next page etc..) and need my $limiter to select 9 querys per page. The issue I am having is that the second page (9,9) does not come in.

```
if(isset($_GET["p"]) && is_numeric($_GET["p"]) && $_GET["p"] > 1) {
        $currentPage = $_GET["p"];
        $limiter = $currentPage * 9;
} else {
        $currentPage = 1;
        $limiter = 0;
}

$finalQuery = "SELECT * FROM forum_replies WHERE thread_id = '1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT " . $limiter . ",9";
```

So if page is 1, $limiter is 0. So.. 0,9 comes in

Next should be 9,9 but the code completley skips that so I am missing out on page two

Page three works which is 18,9

So.. it goes 0,9 - 18,9, 27,9 etc.. completely skipping 9,9. What would I add to my if(isset)) function to make it select all if it and not skip 9,9.

Comment: read the comment in my answer your assumption is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong i think your calculations for $limiter variable is incorrect.
it should be $limiter = ($currentPage - 1) * 9;

```
if(isset($_GET["p"]) && is_numeric($_GET["p"]) && $_GET["p"] > 1) {
    $currentPage = $_GET["p"];
    $limiter = ($currentPage -1) * 9;
} else {
    $currentPage = 1;
    $limiter = 0;
}

$finalQuery = "SELECT * FROM forum_replies WHERE thread_id = '1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT " . $limiter . ",9";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing page 1 because of your `if condition`.

```
if(isset($_GET["p"]) && is_numeric($_GET["p"]) && $_GET["p"] > 1) {
```

this is set to skip the paging logic unless of the page is greater than 1. So it misses page = 1.

based on your code only if `p` is 0 your code will render 0,9 if the p = 1 then your code renders 9,9

Comment: No because after the IF, there's the else code saying current page is 1. Page 1 is not the issue it's page two.

Comment: Is there any way around this so the starting point can be p=1 (0,9) p=2 (9,9) etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
if(isset($_GET["p"]) && is_numeric($_GET["p"]) && $_GET["p"] > 1) {
```

to this:

```
if(isset($_GET["p"]) && is_numeric($_GET["p"]) && $_GET["p"] >= 1) {
```

And this:

```
$limiter = $currentPage * 9;
```

to this:

```
$limiter = ($currentPage-1) * 9;
```

because if $currentPage is 1, you want your limits to be 0,9.

Comment: He was faster :). Just be sure to change $_GET["p"] > 1 to $_GET["p"] >= 1. Cheers!